# Getting the folder path of the last location i right clicked

Tags: c#, registry, explorer

I created a right click shortcut entry (in Explorer's right click context menu) for my application, and I want to get the folder path of the right clicked location, how do i do it?

My code to create the shortcut:

```
RegistryKey rKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Directory\Background\shell", true);
String[] names = rKey.GetSubKeyNames();
foreach (String s in names)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s);
}
RegistryKey newKey = rKey.CreateSubKey("Create HTML Folder");
RegistryKey newSubKey = newKey.CreateSubKey("command");
newSubKey.SetValue("", @"C:\Users\Aviv\Desktop\basicFileCreator.exe " + "\"" + "%1" + "\"");
newSubKey.Close();
newKey.Close();
rKey.Close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you wanna capture the folder path ? Inside your code of basicFileCreator.exe ?

Comment: i want the button to create a file or a folder when i am clicking it.(but at the same folder i right clicked)

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you have an application which is registered with Windows Explorer's context menu, and what you need is the folder path which you right click on.
Well, if this is the case, then I would like to tell you, it's not going to work the way you are expecting.

For this specific purpose, you need the following keys instead of yours:

```
RegistryKey rKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Directory\shell", true);
String[] names = rKey.GetSubKeyNames();
foreach (String s in names)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s);
}
RegistryKey newKey = rKey.CreateSubKey("Create HTML Folder");
RegistryKey newSubKey = newKey.CreateSubKey("command");
newSubKey.SetValue("", @"C:\Users\Aviv\Desktop\basicFileCreator.exe " + "\"" + "%1" + "\"");
newSubKey.Close();
newKey.Close();
rKey.Close();
```

With that done, now we are ready to implement this functionality in our application.
To do it, add the following code to **Program.cs** file of your solution:

```
static class Program
{
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] arguments)//Windows passes an array of arguments which may be filesnames or folder names.
{
    string avivsfolder = @"\Aviv";
    string folderpath = "";

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    if (arguments.Length > 0)//If an argument has been passed.
    {
        folderpath = arguments[0];
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(folderpath))//Make sure the folder exists.
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath + avivsfolder);

                if (Directory.Exists(folderpath + avivsfolder))//To check if the folder was made successfully,if not an exception would stop program exceution,thus no need for 'else' clause.
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The specified folder was created successfully.", "Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

            }

            else
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("The specified folder does not exist");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Aviv's Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    else//No argument passed.
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to select a folder to continue.", "Aviv's Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
  }
}
```

With that,I guess that's enough to get the job done, and [here](http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/661d6966) is the sample project if you need.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: first of all, thanks you for helping me but what i've looked its like create a new folder (clicking on the new > folder)

Comment: it worked, but not as i wanted it to work because every time i clicked on a folder it opened the app. i just want it to be in the context menu and when ill click it will create a folder in the same folder.

Comment: @AvivMamon Updated. The project I've attached as a sample was just to show you that there's much that can be with a shortcut entry.

Comment: @AvivMamon The updated code only creates a folder inside the selected folder,and if successful displays a MessageBox with message,by the way if you need complete silence,just remove the MessageBox statements.